# Can't see method of dll class

Tags: c#

I've created a dll with this class:

```
namespace Trace
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Get the stack
    /// </summary>

    public class Tracers
    {
        public string getTrace() 
        {
            return "test";
        }
    }
}
```

I have compiled the project, included the dll inside another solution and try to access to `getTrace()` method like this:

```
Tracers.getTrace();
```

but I get:

> it must be a reference for the property, the method or the field not static 'Trace.Tracers.getTrace()'

I don't know what I did wrong. Another strange things is that if I write only `Tracers.` the intellisense menu appear and show me only:

1. Equals
2. ReferenceEquals

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have an instance of `Tracers`, so only static methods are visible.

Making the method `static` would work:

```
public static string getTrace() 
{
    return "test";
}
```

Or create an instance of `Tracers`:

```
Tracers t = new Tracers();
t.getTrace();
```

Also note that naming conventions require `getTrace` to have a capital `G`, so: `GetTrace`.

Comment: Oh thanks for this, a stupid error for me.. Have a good day :)

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
Tracers t = new Tracers();
t.getTrace();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the method as `static` like below

```
namespace Trace
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Get the stack
    /// </summary>

    public class Tracers
    {
        public static string getTrace() 
        {
            return "test";
        }
    }
}
```

then you can access method this way

```
Tracers.getTrace();
```

or if want to use your present code then you need to instantiate class before method invoke

```
Tracers trace = new Tracers();
trace.getTrace();
```

Comment: You are 11 minutes too late.